# i need to keep hyphen if column is empty i am using ngif but it doesnt work

Tags: angular

I need to add Hyphen to column if i am not getting data from the service.
I am using below code but it is not working

```
{{element.j1RangeLs | date :'dd-MMM-yyy' }} <br>
<span *ngIf = "j1RangeLs =='' && j1RangeJ1 =='' "> - </span> <br>
{{element.j1RangeJ1 | date :'dd-MMM-yyy' }}
```

Comment: Have you tried the modified demo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator `?` to display `-` if value is null

Try like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let element of data">
  {{element.j1RangeLs | date :'dd-MMM-yyy'}}
  <span *ngIf="element.j1RangeLs && element.j1RangeJ1">-</span>
  {{element.j1RangeJ1 | date :'dd-MMM-yyy'}}
</p>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esyn5v?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: there are two data ranges in a column i need to diplay hyphne if data is missing for both.
j1RangeJ1 and j1RangeLs are both different date ranges for single column.

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: I need to display hyphen when two dates are available.
like this
12-Aug-2019
-
13-May-2020

Comment: Ok. Check themodified demo